# Print layout is rasterized before exporting as SVG

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, export, svg

So I've set up my layer to how I'd like for it to be exported as an SVG, but after adding the map to New Print Layout, it rasterizes my layer and makes it unusable in my other program. Is there a way to export my svg without rasterizing it first?

[image: This is in QGIS before adding my map to a new print layout.]
This is in QGIS before adding my map to a new print layout

[image: This is after]
This is after

Comment: Check the `Export map layers as SVG groups` option in the SVG export from layouts

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I have tried this and it doesn't seem to help much unfortunately.

Comment: What is your vector layer type?

Comment: Line (Multilinestrings)

Comment: So, shapefile with multlines ? I will check, what I had tried when making my first comment solved it for a shapefile with lines.